# What is this small rotating part from a cell phone?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, consumer-electronics

What is this tiny rotating piece of hardware that I found inside my Samsung GE1202? It has E9C written in blue on it.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These types of motor configurations are used in the cellphone's vibrate/buzzer function. Here is a Youtube video demonstrating the vibrate function and two other references:

- [How it works:Cell phone vibration motor?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWgN20Xx-5A)
- [iPhone 5 / 5S Vibrator Motor Replacement](https://www.strivemobile.com/iphone-5-5s-vibrator-motor-replacement?gclid=CK2Xi7n868YCFVYTHwodULwDFA)
- [Vibration Motors by Precision Microdrives](http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/vibrating-vibrator-vibration-motors)

[image: diagram of motor with eccentric rotating mass]
<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

These are called Eccentric Rotating Mass (ERM) vibration motors. This type of motor technology is also used in haptic feedback technology.

---

**References:**

- [Rotating unbalance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_unbalance)
- [Haptic Feedback](http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/haptics-haptic-feedback-vibration-alerting)
- [Haptics Solutions for ERM and LRA Actuators](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEwQFjAHahUKEwi3hqvPgOzGAhUCGh4KHTUuDcU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fpdf%2Fsszb151&ei=hB2uVbe0LYK0eLXctKgM&usg=AFQjCNEPZ6ZhM3YADI4Gz6fW79eeCbNKvA&sig2=OYt3Pcxu6ndfrV04FFbVWQ)
- [Haptics technology: picking up good vibrations](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1278948)

Answer (score 6):

That is a micro vibrating motor to produce the "buzz" effect from your phone. 
I used much [much larger vibrating motors](http://www.chicagovibrator.com/Store/tabid/84/c/truck-vibrators/Default.aspx), air driven, on the bottom of my Class 7 dump truck. Mounted under the bed, they would vibrate the bed, loosening the material so it would flow out cleanly.

Comment: +1 for the dump truck vibrator - I'd never seen them before